# java IOException when parsing a URL of a page for creating a DOM using TagSoup

Tags: java, dom, ioexception, tag-soup

Usng the following link I am trying to create a DOM tree of the URL (thats a specific URL that returns this exception) :

```
     String url="http://www.kingfisher.org/";

    Parser p = new Parser();
    SAX2DOM sax2dom ;
    org.w3c.dom.Node doc ;

    p.setFeature(Parser.namespacesFeature, false);
    p.setFeature(Parser.namespacePrefixesFeature, false);
    sax2dom = new SAX2DOM(true);
    p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
    p.parse(new InputSource(url));
    doc = sax2dom.getDOM();
```

but whn I run my program for this URL, it gives me the excepton at `p.parse(new InputSource(url));` which I dont know why. cause so far it had no problem whatsoever.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.kingfisher.org/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.getInputStream(Parser.java:510)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.getReader(Parser.java:487)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.parse(Parser.java:440)
at pageparsertest.PageParserTest.main(PageParserTest.java:92)
```

any hint?

Comment: Maybe try using the `URL` class and then instead of `new InputSource()` you can use `url.openStream()`.

Comment: @Ihsan do you mean I write `p.parse(url.openstream());` ?

Comment: Yes, and change your `String url` to an `URL` object.

Comment: @Ihsan but t says no suitable method found for that line of code even I made a URL object

Comment: @Ihsan in fact it should be `            p.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())));` though it still gives same exception

Comment: Did the answer of @abdotalaat work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68121/discussion-between-ihsan-and-lonesome).

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use HttpURLConnection you should be able to access the request of web page from java. Try the following code:

```
String url = "http://www.kingfisher.org/";
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
        p.parse(new InputSource(httpcon.getInputStream()));
```